# Extract email id from text file by showing path

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-extraction

---

my text file is saved on my desktop which contains my resume i want to extract my E-mail from the text file can some one help me 
My txt file has

```
Name                        :      K. Spandana

Gender                      :      Female

Nationality                 :      Indian

Marital Status              :      Unmarried
Mother tongue               :      Telugu
Languages Known             :      English, Hindi and Telugu
Address of Correspondence   :      H.NO:4-56/1, Hanuman nagar ,Post: Theegalaguttapalli,

E-mail ID                   :      Spandanareddy.kallepu@gmail.com
```

i have tried 
https://gist.github.com/dideler/5219706 code with file path

Comment: can you let us know what have u tried and what is the exact issue you are facing if any?

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will work:

```
with open('resume.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    print re.findall(r'\b([a-z0-9-_.]+?@[a-z0-9-_.]+)\b', f_input.read(), re.I)
```

It will display:

```
['Spandanareddy.kallepu@gmail.com']
```

But the exact logic can be [far more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address). It all depends on how accurate it needs to be.

This will display all email addresses in the text file, just in case there is more than one.